# Regarding input to NetTrain function

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

Essentially I have used the SemanticImport[] function on a csv file with headers for each column. Now I understand that each of these headers is referred to 'key' in mathematica. *

I have no problem doing Predict[]. But I understand that **NetTrain requires a different input format**
 I was looking under Association, but have not found clarity in doing this.

Thank you and appreciate your advice.

---

**Following reply by aardvark2012:**

I ran the following lines:

```
net = NetChain[{5, 1}, "Input" -> 8, "Output" -> "Scalar"];
trained = NetTrain[net, inputdata]
```

But an error is shown:

```
NetTrain::invdataset: Datasets provided to NetTrain must consist of a list of associations with fixed keys.
```

---

UPDATE: solved by xslittlegrass. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to work. Set up some data:

```
assocdata = 
 Table[Association["Latitude" -> RandomInteger[{-90, 90}], 
   "Longitude" -> RandomInteger[{-180, 180}], 
   "Temperature" -> RandomReal[{-40, 49}]], 5]
```

> {<|"Latitude" -> 64, "Longitude" -> 25,    "Temperature" ->
>   -24.8889|>, <|"Latitude" -> -49,    "Longitude" -> -101, "Temperature" -> -28.0145|>, <|"Latitude" -> 9,    "Longitude" -> -112,    "Temperature" -> 22.6383|>, <|"Latitude" -> -65, "Longitude" -> 150,
>   "Temperature" -> 13.6052|>, <|"Latitude" -> 25, "Longitude" -> 110,
>   "Temperature" -> 29.0704|>}

Then

```
listdata = {#[[1]], #[[2]]} -> #[[3]] & /@ assocdata
```

gives

> {{64, 25} -> -24.8889, {-49, -101} -> -28.0145, {9, -112} -> 
>     22.6383, {-65, 150} -> 13.6052, {25, 110} -> 29.0704}

Is that what you meant?

Comment: yes, your answer gives me the correct format I am looking for, but somehow NetTrain doesn't like it. Could you have a look at my updated question and would appreciate your advice. Thank you

Comment: @Corse Unfortunately I can't play around with it since I'm on 10.4 and NetTrain is 11+. The only guess I can make is that it wants an input of the form `Association["Lattiude" -> assocdata[[;; , 1]], 
 "Longitude" -> assocdata[[;; , 2]], 
 "Temperature" -> assocdata[[;; , 3]]]' (where `assocdata` has the same form as in my answer). Not convinced it'll work, though, since it's not a "list of associations with fixed keys". Not even sure what a _fixed_ key is. Is it perhaps interpreting your `latitude`, etc as variable names? Sorry, but I'm just guessing now.

Comment: I would trawl through the documentation on all the different `*Layer`s (`Linear`, `Elementwise`, etc), play around with them and see if you can figure out what they're doing.

Comment: @Corse No problem. Thanks for the accept.

Answer (score 3):

I think aardvark2012's answer is correct, this is just a comment on your follow-up questions. Your follow-up questions can be addressed by providing `NetTrain` with the compatible training data formats.

You can either use a `Dataset` or a list as training data. If a Dataset is used, then the format should be like `Dataset[{<|"Input" -> {64, 25}, "Output" -> -24.8889|>, <|"Input" -> {-49, -101}, "Output" -> -28.0145|>}]`. For example

```
inputdata = 
 Dataset@Table[
   Association["Input" -> RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2}], 
    "Output" -> RandomReal[{0, 1}]], {10}]
```

[image]

then you can train the network like

```
net = NetChain[{5, 1}, "Input" -> 2, "Output" -> "Scalar"];
trained = NetTrain[net, inputdata]
```

If using a list, then the training data should be like `{{64, 25} -> -24.8889, {-49, -101} -> -28.0145, {9, -112} -> 22.6383, {-65, 150} -> 13.6052, {25, 110} -> 29.0704}`. For example

```
inputdata = 
 Table[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2}] -> RandomReal[{0, 1}], {10}];

net = NetChain[{5, 1}, "Input" -> 2, "Output" -> "Scalar"];
trained = NetTrain[net, inputdata]
```

You can also specify the input and output ports with NetGraph, which then allow you to train on a Dataset with named keys directly. For example

```
inputdata = Dataset[Association[Thread[header -> #]] & /@ data]
```

[image]

```
net = NetGraph[{ReshapeLayer[{1}], ReshapeLayer[{1}], CatenateLayer[],
    LinearLayer[5], LinearLayer[1]}, {NetPort["lat"] -> 1 -> 3, 
   NetPort["lon"] -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> NetPort["temperature"]}]
```

[image]

```
NetTrain[net, inputdata, Method -> {"ADAM", "LearningRate" -> 0.01}]
```

Hope it helps.

---

Here is an example of how to read in and train on a csv dataset

```
path = 
 Export["~/Downloads/test.csv", 
  Table[{RandomReal[{-90, 90}], RandomReal[{-180, 180}], 
    RandomReal[{-50, 50}]}, {100}]]
(* "~/Downloads/test.csv" *)

inputdata = #[[1 ;; 2]] -> #[[3]] & /@ Import[path, "Data"];

net = NetChain[{5, 1}, "Input" -> 2, "Output" -> "Scalar"];
trained = 
 NetTrain[net, inputdata, Method -> {"ADAM", "LearningRate" -> 0.01}]
```

another example using dataset

```
path = 
 Export["~/Downloads/test.txt", 
  StringRiffle[
   Prepend[Table[
     StringRiffle[
      ToString[NumberForm[#, {3, 4}]] & /@ {RandomReal[{-90, 90}], 
        RandomReal[{-180, 180}], RandomReal[{-50, 50}]}, 
      "\t"], {100}], 
    StringRiffle[{"lat", "lon", "temperature"}, "\t"]], "\n"]]
(* "~/Downloads/test.txt" *)

tmp = Import[path, "Table"];


inputdata = 
  Association["Input" -> #[[1 ;; 2]], "Output" -> #[[3]]] & /@ 
   Rest@tmp;

net = NetChain[{5, 1}, "Input" -> 2, "Output" -> "Scalar"];
trained = 
 NetTrain[net, inputdata, Method -> {"ADAM", "LearningRate" -> 0.01}]
```

Comment: thank you for the clarification. I refer to this:  Association["Input" -> RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2}], 
    "Output" -> RandomReal[{0, 1}]], {10}]. How could I replace the RandomReal part using the Keys in my dataset? say I have header as "lat", "lon" and "temperature" from the CSV file.

Comment: @Corse See the updates.

Comment: this works well and that was very enlightening and helpful for my understanding on the input formats of NetTrain/NetGraph. Thank you very much!

Comment: a minor question to seek your advice: for the purposes of regression/prediction, is it normally recommended to put a BatchNormalizationLayer[] as the first hidden layer? Does it have the effect of scaling the values of each variable and is it at all necessary in Mathematica?

Comment: one more query if you don't mind, if i have an additional column (input variable) that is of a class vector, how could I modify the part: inputdata = #[[1 ;; 2]] -> #[[3]] & /@ Import[path, "Data"]; to utilize the NetEncoder function for 'UnitVector'?

Comment: @Corse Usually it's a good idea to normalize the data before training. Notice that I used to `"LearningRate" -> 0.01` in the above examples. This is exactly because the data is normalized and the default learning rate would not converge. Since you know your data range, you can just normalize your data with scaling factors. I think BatchNormalizationLayer is meant to normalize activations between layers. For the UnitVector encoding, see the Titanic survival example in NetTrain->Applications->Classifiying Categorical Data.

Comment: I see, thank you for the clarification. I refer to this: 'I think BatchNormalizationLayer is meant to normalize activations between layers'. Could you elaborate in slightly more detail what this entails? I tried referring to the documentation but found it to be lacking (not sure if it is just me though).

Comment: For the Titanic example you have mentioned, for example, there was no scaling done for the 'Age' category. I'm sure this example is simplified for clearer understanding, but should we, as a rule-of-thumb- always scale our data beforehand? Will it help in accuracy, or is it merely a processing time optimization?

Comment: For batch normalization, you can have a look at [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03167.pdf), or the CS231n course. Data normalization will in general help the convergence of the gradient descent process. See more details in the "Gradient'descent'in'
prac2ce'I:'Feature'Scaling" in [this course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning).